# Method '+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:' not found when trying to use animateWithDuration

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

```
-(void)fadeLabel{

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:kLabelTag];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         label.alpha = 0.0;


                     }];



}
```

My first attempt at animating anything has given me:
Method '+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:' not found when trying to use animateWithDuration

I have no clue as to what is causing this error, but my code is the same as all the other tutorials and guides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is actually `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. You're missing the `completion:` bit. You can just pass `nil` to that argument if you don't need a completion block.

Comment: @Adam: If my answer satisfied your question, please mark it as accepted so the question doesn't stay open.